# How to add an attr (id) to a <text> tag of a specific value-Js/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 text values all having class names as attributes. however im trying to add some styling to specific text only:eg

```
<text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 1</text>
<text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 2</text>
<text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 3</text>
```

Now im trying to add an a unique id to the second text above. How can i put a condition to see if a  has specific value add attr('id'),
pseudo code:

```
if($("text.text").text() == 'Text 2'){
   $("text.text").attr("id", "text-id");
}
```

if i do the above way, all the text tags are set with the 'id'. how can i add the 'id' to just one ? Any help appreciated..

Comment: Your html is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.text').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Text 2"){
        $(this).attr('id','CustomID');
    }
});
```

Fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/9spwrxd9/

Answer (score 2):

use filter()

```
$("text.text").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == 'Text 2'
}).attr("id", "text-id");
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```js
$("text.text").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'Text 2') {
    $(this).attr("id", "text-id");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 1</text>
<text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 2</text>
<text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 3</text>
```